# draw line across in a ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a plot where I'd like to draw a line from `(0,0)` to
`(15,15)`, with legend. How do I achieve that? Plot:

```
frame <- read.table('pastie_from_web', sep=",", header=TRUE)
colnames(frame) <- c("pos", "word.length")
plot <- ggplot(frame, aes(x=pos, y=word.length)) + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1,15)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1,15))+ geom_density2d(aes(color=..level..)) + scale_color_gradient(low="black", high="red") + opts(legend.position="none")
png(paste("graphs/", fname, ".png", sep=""), width=600, height=600)
print(plot)
```

Data: http://sprunge.us/gKiL or

```
structure(list(position = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 8, 4, 5, 4, 9, 5, 
2, 7, 9, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 2, 6, 5, 5, 7, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5, 3, 2, 4, 
5, 2, 3, 2, 7, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 8, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 
6, 8, 2, 2, 9, 5, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 7, 2, 7, 2, 
4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 8, 7, 5, 7, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 
6, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 6, 2), word.length = c(5L, 5L, 6L, 
4L, 9L, 11L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 
9L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 
8L, 16L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 
16L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 6L, 13L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 7L, 6L, 13L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 
10L)), .Names = c("position", "word.length"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-106L))
```

Comment: Please use `dput(data)` and paste that result (or part of it `dput(head(data))`) instead of posting data somewhere else on the web.

Comment: perhaps `geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = 15, yend = 15))`. It's not clear what you are showing in the legend though.

Comment: What @Maiasaura said or if you don't want to `dput()` here, at least show the code used to read that file from the web so we don't have to figure it out ourselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example data set to illustrate:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(20, min = 0, max = 20),
                  y = runif(20, min = 0, max = 20))

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) 
p + geom_point() + 
    geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(0,15), y = c(0,15)),
              aes = aes(x = x, y = y), colour = "red")
```

Notice how we can specify different `data` argument to geoms, which allows us to plot different data objects on the same plot regions defined in the original `ggplot()` call. **Note:** If the second data frame (in the `geom_line()` call) has the same x and y axis mapping as the original plot, then you don't need a new `aes()` as I originally had the code (see revision history of the Answer). This may not have been clear and the comment from @Justin has prompted me to change the `geom_line()` to include a new `aes()` call to map the data to the aesthetics; it is not needed in my example but may well be needed in real world use.

The above gives:

[image]

If you want different arbitrary lines, consider `geom_abline()` to draw lines with give slope and intercept. `geom_segment()` is an alternative to the above `geom_line()` where you specify the start and end x and y coordinates. See the respective help pages for the geoms to determine which you prefer the use of.

Comment: I added `plot <- plot + geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(0,15), y = c(0,15)), colour = "green")` to the file, which gives me `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'pos' not found
Calls: lapply ... sapply -> lapply -> eval.quoted -> lapply -> FUN -> eval`.

Comment: you didn't supply a new `aes(...)` for the `geom_line` so its trying to use the one defined in the first `ggplot`.  Instead add the appropriate `aes` like in Gavin's answer or change the names of the `geom_line` data.frame to match.

Comment: +1 Good point @Justin I didn't include a new `aes(...)` in the `geom_line()` call *because* the mapping of variable `x` to the x-axis and `y` to the y-axis remained the same as the initial `ggplot()` but that might not be clear. I'll change the code above to reflect this.